# How to identify which Google user account any particular push notification is intended for (A13)?

Tags: notifications, google-account, logging, accounts, push-notifications

Long story short, my wife has many accounts (against my advisement), and one of them is sending Find Device push notifications that aren't being pinged by either of us.  I advised her to check all her GMail accounts for security notices, but she doesn't wish to do so (no idea why).

Just to humor her, I'm thinking of taking a look for her but other than sifting through logcat, is there any other method to enumerate/filter this information, whether programmatically or otherwise?

She has a OnePlus 10 [TMO][Stock][A13]

Comment: On another note, would this question fit better at SU?  It's not that I'm not looking for any native solutions, I just think it far more likely the solution will involve ADB.

Comment: ADB solution is certainly on-topic here, including solutions related to shell/terminal commands, 3rd-party apps, or even perhaps external sites (e.g. Google My Activity). On the other hand, based on current wording, I think the question will be deemed as off-topic at SU because it's unclear if the Android device is interfacing with a computer.